# How to do find posted delivery and deliver it to integration stream?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

we are using UCM in multisite environment. Whenever people delivering to mastersite , Some one from mastersite has to do find posted deliveries and then deliver it to integration stream again.

Now we want to preview what are all the files being delivered to integration stream.

`Cleartool delivery -stream "Stream" -to "Integration-view" -preview` did not work as it is trying to deliver activities to stream.

I found the article "[Find UCM Posted deliveries](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21126522)

In this article , there is a way to find posted deliveries and complete it. but i need to preview before complete it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OP Samselvaprabu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/399145/samselvaprabu) insists on the multisite aspect of that deliver, pointing to an [IBM article on those "posted delivers"](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21126522).

Since a multisite deliver doesn't handle well any preview option, I would then recommend to:

- have a local integration Stream in sync with the distant site (to which youwant to eventually deliver those activities)
- initiate a *local* deliver to that local Integration Stream (that will support the `-preview` option too)
- examine those "deliver activities" locally, before, if their content is satisfactory, initiate the actual (multisite) deliver.

---

Original answer

You can add the activities you want to deliver

```
 cleartool deliver -act
```

(See [`cleartool deliver` man page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm))

Knowing that those activities are beginning by deliver, you can list them, sorted by date, pick the new ones and list them in the act parameter.

```
-act/ivities activity-selector, ...
```

> Specifies a list of activities to deliver. The list must be self-consistent: the activities specified must not depend on the inclusion of any unspecified activities.
>   For example, activity `A2` is dependent on activity `A1` if both contain versions of the same element and A2 contains a later version than does `A1`.
>
> In addition, any activities that have been included in baselines but not delivered must also be delivered if changes for that component are in the specified activities. If the list of activities you specify is incomplete, the operation fails and lists the additional required activities.
>
> activity-selector is of the form `[activity:]activity-name[@vob-selector]` where `vob-selector` specifies the activity's project VOB.

Comment: I am trying to find preview for find posted deliveries. I think your comment leads to find list of activities to be delivered. Moreover i am not sure whether it works with find posted deliveries

Comment: @Samselvaprabu from the list of activities, you can make the deliver with the right activities.  Ie your deliver -preview you were mentioning in your question.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu But even simpler, when you have the right list of activities is to describe them,  listing the files within them.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu my last comment is actually the safest solution since a deliver -preview or a fundmerge -preview will only list the directories to be merged, not the files.

Comment: I have edited my question for more clarity. I think it will help you to understand easier. The solution you provided to me deals with activity deliver. But in multisite "Find posted delivery" scenario, it would not handle.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: the best way is to describe each activity your command is given you. And `merge -preview` will stop at the directory and won't always details the files to be merged.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu One way would be to make the deliver locally, before doing it on a distant site: if you do it on a local Integration Stream in sync with the distant site, then you can try and preview it.

Comment: I think your last comment would be an answer

Comment: @Samselvaprabu: I have updated my answer with my latest proposal from the comments.